# Bootstrap 5.0 Hamburger menu icon doesn't show up

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

experts - I'm trying to solve what I think should be a simple issue. I'm looking at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#toggler and trying to implement the hamburger menu that shows up when the window is narrow (e.g. phone screen). When I make the window narrow, the button is still invisible. When I move the mouse to where the menu should be, the cursor turns into the pointer. When I click it, the button's outline becomes bold (so I can see it), and the drop down menu shows up. However, the hamburger menu icon is still invisible. What am I doing wrong? I feel like I pretty much copied the code verbatim from the documentation.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Hello, world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" style="margin-left: 20px" href="#"
          >Example Name</a
        >

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler bg-light"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"
                >Option 1</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing class `navbar-light` here

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
```

it should be

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

This is the Bootstrap class definition in `_navbar.scss`

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 0.55%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```

**Example**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Hello, world</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" style="margin-left: 20px" href="#">Example Name</a
        >

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler bg-light"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"
                >Option 1</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**

> where did you find _navbar.scss, and how did you know to look there?

I used the Chorme dev tools to find it. The below image explains how I found the missing class and the filename in which the class is mentioned. The file can be accessed in the [Bootstrap Github source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_navbar.scss). Background image is mentioned [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_navbar.scss#L240)

> ...wouldn't have thought that navbar-light would control anything but
> the color scheme of the navbar, let alone whether an icon appears
> somewhere in it

Icon depends on the navbar background for better visibility. Thats why its dependent on `navbar-light`

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where did you find _navbar.scss, and how did you know to look there? I looked at the documentation linked in the OP, and wouldn't have thought that navbar-light would control anything but the color scheme of the navbar, let alone whether an icon appears somewhere in it.